# Split IOB file in train and test set with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-processing, named-entity-recognition

I have a large dataset in IOB format that I want to cut into a training set and a test set with an 80:20 ratio like:

```
df[0:15]
```

```
    form    morph
2   GRIMALTE    B-PERS
3   AMANT   O
4   DE  O
5   LA  O
6   dame    B-PERS
7   Gradisse    B-PERS
8   narre   O
9   sommairement    O
10  Les     O
11  amoureux    O
12  regredz     O
13  de  O
14  Flamete     B-PERS
15  ,   O
16  qui     O
```

After splitted the dataframe in two with the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from math import floor

def split_train_test_dataset(data_df, ratio_train=0.8):

    records = data_df.to_records(index=False).tolist()
    split_index = floor(len(records) * ratio_train)

    train = records[:split_index]
    test = records[split_index:]

    df_train = pd.DataFrame(train, columns =['WORD', 'NER'])
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns =['WORD', 'NER'])

    return df_train, df_test

data_df = df

train_set, test_set = split_train_test_dataset(data_df)

print(train_set[-20:])
print(test_set[0:20])

print(f'Total size of train set : {len(train_set)}')
print(f'Total size of test set : {len(test_set)}')
```

I get the following output:

```
Train_set
    WORD    NER
3880307     jusqu'  O
3880308     au  O
3880309     -   O
3880310     bas     O
3880311     ;   O
3880312     d'  O
3880313     où  O
3880314     l'on    O
3880315     voit    O
3880316     par     O
3880317     ce  O
3880318     qui     O
3880319     vient   O
3880320     d'  O
3880321     être    O
3880322     dit     O
3880323     ,   O
3880324     que     O
3880325     les     O
3880326     des     O
        
Test_set
    WORD    NER
0   fusées  O
1   ne  O
2   sont    O
3   pas     O
4   exactement  O
5   les     O
6   mêmes   O
7   ,   O
8   &   O
9   qu'     O
10  elles   O
11  sont    O
12  relatives   O
13  aux     O
14  différentes     O
15  forces  O
16  des     O
17  ressorts    O
18  .   O
19      

Total size of train set : 3880327
Total size of test set : 970082
```

However, the last sentence of the train set is cut and continues on the test set (index 18 in test_set).

In the IOB file, each sentence being separated by a whitespace, would it be possible to define a pattern (in addition to the ratio) to be sure that the train set ends with an end of a sentence?

Or do I have to manually add the end of the test_set sentence in the train_set file ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Split your data into sentences, and then split off 80% of sentences, not rows/words.